# Is there any way to have switch between 2 maven_server inside a workspace?

Tags: bazel

one points to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 and the other to a private artifactory?

```
maven_server(
   name = "default",
   url = "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2",
)

maven_server(
   name = "default",
   url = "<some private maven repo>",
)
```

Basically, what I wanted to do is use http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 as the default when developing in my local machine and switch to another maven_server (e.g. http://intranet.mycorp.net) when doing prod builds outside my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Skylark implementation of `maven_jar`? It's available in `@bazel_tools`.

You can use it by adding this line to the top of your `WORKSPACE`

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:maven_rules.bzl", "maven_jar")`
```

This implementation will allow you to use a custom `settings.xml` using the `maven_jar.settings` attribute because it calls `mvn` directly. Note that the `server` attribute is removed from this implementation, since server settings are specified in `settings.xml`. For example,

```
maven_jar(
  name = "foo",
  artifact = "foo:foo:1.0",
  settings = "//:private_settings.xml",
)

maven_jar(
  name = "bar",
  artifact = "bar:bar:1.0",
  settings = "//:other_settings.xml",
)
```